# Choice between 2 investments that cost the same but offer different interest and face value

Tags: investment, present-value

Assume, you have a choice between two investments that both cost \$1000 each, however investment A pays \$20 a year and \$950 at the end of year 5 but investment B pays \$10 a year and \$1000 at the end of the 5 years. Which investment should I choose based on it offering a better return?

Comment: zhqiat makes a good suggestion but this type of question is not appropriate for this site, please see the [faq].

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you calculate the IRR of each investment? (aside from all the issues with [IRR](http://www.investopedia.com/exam-guide/cfa-level-1/corporate-finance/advantages-disadvantages-npv-net-present-value-irr-internal-rate-of-return.asp)).